# Read "application/octet-stream; charset=binary" file in Informatica

Tags: hex, informatica

i am trying to load a file in Informatica having filetype 'application/octet-stream; charset=binary' and kept codepage 'ms windows latin 1 (ansi) superset of latin1'

Original data

1^\MI^\IN^\123^\Y^^

Replaced HEX character using TR command

1|MI|IN|123|Y

After file processing Hex characters ^\ are added at the end of each line as below. how to deal with these extra characters in Informatica.

"1|MI|IN|123|Y^\^\^\^\^\"

Comment: Could you please use `sed -i '' -e 's/[^[:print:]][^[:print:]]*/ /g' inpfile.dat` to replace hex characters with space and then  informatica can check it.

Comment: I've replaced the hex chars before processing the file  but still these chars are added at the end of the file

Comment: how you are replacing them? if you replace them how they are appearing?

Comment: thats the question, ever after replacing why they are appearing again. may be due to codepage, actually i am sure.

Comment: by 'how' i mean which exact command are you using ? Is it possible for you to try  `sed -i '' -e 's/[^[:print:]][^[:print:]]*/ /g' inpfile.dat` ?